# GRPC status run time exception while refreshing access token in google cloud data flow

Tags: python, access-token, apache-beam, dataflow

I am running a data flow job to fetch data from pubsub and passing on to big query. But during this process, I am getting the following error after 1 hour of run.

```
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Refreshing due to a 401 (attempt 1/2)
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:root:2018-12-19T09:13:09.510Z: JOB_MESSAGE_ERROR: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: cancelled before receiving half close

java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MoreFutures.get(MoreFutures.java:57)
```

Please help me resolving the error.
If I am not wrong, is this the problem while getting refreshed access tokens ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

When we leave for a while and wait for the next access token, the dataflow keeps running and fetches the values as expected. But still couldnt figure out the root cause. Is it because of network issue where the request and response gets delayed ?